# Finding all the values from one specific element

Tags: java

I have a list of animals and some information about them, what do I do if I want a user to be able to find for an animal and its information by typing the animal's name? I have stored the animals in a list like this:

```
List<Animal> an = new ArrayList<Animal>();
Animal a4 = new Animal();
a4.add("Tiffany", 10, "Giraffe", "Grass");
a4.add("Mayo", 30, "Elephant", "Water");
a4.add("Simba", 30, "Turtle", "Leaves");
```

Comment: Please provide some more context and show any code you have written so far.

Comment: For something like this, where you want the user to be able to get an animal by its name, you're probably going to want to use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) rather than a `List`.

Comment: `an.stream().findFirst(a -> a.name.equals(inputData)).get();`

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy at first I actually used a map (not very familiar with them though) but I could only get the name and the 2nd value to print. Not sure how it works if you have 1 key and multiple values

Comment: @Barrenr Be more creative with the `value`'s type, then. Either have the key be `String` and the value be `Animal`, or if you need multiple `Animal` objects with the same name, then have the value always be `List<Animal>` containing all the `Animal` objects with that name.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've an `Animal` class like this:

```
public class Animal {
    String name;
    int age;
    String breed;
    String eats;

   // getters, setters, constructor with fields

}
```

with Java 8:

```
List<Animal> an = new ArrayList<Animal>();
an.add(new Animal("Tiffany", 10, "Giraffe", "Grass"));
an.add(new Animal("Mayo", 30, "Elephant", "Water"));
an.add(new Animal("Simba", 30, "Turtle", "Leaves"));

// String name = "Mayo"; // commented to get the user input with Scanner
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the animal's name, please...");
String name = scan.nextLine();

Optional<Animal> foundAnimal = an.stream().filter(animal -> animal.getName().equals(name)).findFirst();

if (foundAnimal.isPresent()) { // if the animal is in the list
    System.out.println("Animals name: " + foundAnimal.get().getName() + "\n" + "Animals age: "
            + foundAnimal.get().getAge());
}
```

Also you can achieve this by using a simple `foreach` loop:

```
List<Animal> an = new ArrayList<Animal>();
an.add(new Animal("Tiffany", 10, "Giraffe", "Grass"));
an.add(new Animal("Mayo", 30, "Elephant", "Water"));
an.add(new Animal("Simba", 30, "Turtle", "Leaves"));

//String name = "Mayo"; // commented to get the user input with Scanner
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the animal's name, please...");
String name = scan.nextLine();

for (Animal animal : an) {
    if (animal.getName().equals(name)) {
        System.out.println("Animals name: " + animal.getName() + "\n" + "Animals age: " + animal.getAge());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Animals name: Mayo
Animals age: 30
```

Comment: How would you take user input instead of string name = "mayo"? So if a user type "Mayo" then Mayo's information is displayed

Comment: it is up to you, i would use a Scanner to get the user input.

Comment: @Barrenr i made a quick update to get the user input...

Answer (score 1):

Use Map

```
Map<String,Animal> animalsMap=new HashMap<String,Animal>();
animalsMap.put("Tiffany",new Animal("Tiffany", 10, "Giraffe", "Grass"));
animalsMap.put("Tiffany",new Animal("Mayo", 30, "Elephant", "Water"));
animalsMap.put("Simba",new Animal("Simba", 30, "Turtle", "Leaves"));
```

then to get an animal  use:

animalsMap.get("simba")

this can be used with multiple animals called simba if you combine list with map:

```
Map<String,List<Animal>> animalsMap=new HashMap<String,Animal>();
List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animalList.add(new Animal()
Animal a4 = new Animal("Tiffany", 10, "Giraffe", "Grass");
animalList.add(a4);
Animal a4 = new Animal("Tiffany", 11, "boar", "meat");
animalList.add(a4);
animalsMap.put("Tiffany",animalList );

List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animalList.add(new Animal()
Animal a4 = new Animal("simba", 10, "Giraffe", "Grass");
animalList.add(a4);
Animal a4 = new Animal("simba", 11, "boar", "meat");
animalList.add(a4);
animalsMap.put("simba",animalList );
```

last of all if you insist on using a list:

```
Animal result;
list.stream().forEach((a)->{if (a.getName().equals("simba") {result=a});});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your logic. You have creted an ArrayList which will store Animal class objects, so, u need to use an.add(new Animal ( parameters / details)) and later iterate over it. Use the following code for reference -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private int num;
    private String type;
    private String food;

    public Animal(String name, int num, String type, String food) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.num = num;
        this.type = type;
        this.liveon = food;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal [name=" + name + ", num=" + num + ", type=" + type + ", 
                        food=" + food + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<Animal> an = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        
        // Add Address objects to the ArrayList
        an.add(new Animal("Tiffany", 10, "Giraffe", "Grass"));
        an.add(new Animal("Mayo", 30, "Elephant", "Water"));
        an.add(new Animal("Simba", 30, "Turtle", "Leaves"));

        // Iterate over the ArrayList
        for(Animal a:an){
            if(a.getName() == "Simba"){
                System.out.println(a.toString());
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do the for each loop if a user chose the animal? Simply replacing "simba" with the user input wouldn't work

Comment: What do you want to search for exactly ?